# submitting angular form to RESTful API with validation

Tags: angularjs, forms

I am trying to submit my form to my RESTful API. This form was all set up with $validation and $error checking, but now that I've pointed my form directly at the model, all those vars don't exist in the form/object any longer. So this is busted:

```
        console.log(vm.form);
        if (vm.form.$valid) {
```

View:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" name="form" role="form" novalidate ng-init="submitted=false" ng-submit="listingVm.submit()">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title" class="control-label col-xs-3">Title:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" id="title" value="{{ listingVm.form.Title }}">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description" class="control-label col-xs-3">Description:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description" ng-model="listingVm.form.Description" required>
                <div class="error-message" ng-show="listingVm.form.Description.$invalid &&listingVm.form.Description.$touched || listingVm.submitted">
                    <span ng-show="listingVm.form.Description.$error.required">Description is required.</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="value" class="control-label col-xs-3">Value:</label>
            <div class="col-xs-9">
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="value" ng-model="listingVm.form.Value" required>
                <div class="error-message" ng-show="listingVm.form.Value.$invalid && listingVm.form.Value.$touched || listingVm.submitted">
                    <span ng-show="listingVm.form.Value.$error.required">Value is required.</span>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="Id" ng-model="listingVm.form.Id" />

        [{{listingVm.form}}]

        <button class="pull-right btn btn-same" type="submit">Save Changes</button>
    </form>
```

Controller:

```
function editListingController($http, $stateParams, toastr) {
    var vm = this;

    vm.submit = function () {
        vm.submitted = true;

        console.log(vm.form);
        if (vm.form.$valid) {

            $http.put('/api/listings/' + $stateparams.id, vm.formdata).then(function (response) {

            }, function (response) {
                toastr.error(response.data.message);
            });
        }

    };
```

Specifically this:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Description" ng-model="listingVm.form.Description" required>
                    <div class="error-message" ng-show="listingVm.form.Description.$invalid && listingVm.form.Description.$touched || listingVm.submitted">
```

The validation message should pick up listingVm.form.Description.$invalid if the field is empty and touched. But there is no such thing as $invalid on my fields. Where does this come from? Whatever applies these  $ features is missing from my code.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, *there* they are.

I was looking for *listingVm.form.Description*

The validators are in *form.Description*

So, instead of

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Description" ng-model="listingVm.form.Description" required />
    <div class="error-message" ng-show="listingVm.form.Description.$invalid && listingVm.form.Description.$touched || listingVm.submitted">
        <span ng-show="listingVm.form.Description.$error.required">Description is required.</span>
```

the *ng-show* references the form *directly*:

```
ng-show="form.Description.$error.required"
```

So it should be:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="Description" ng-model="listingVm.form.Description" required />
    <div class="error-message" ng-show="form.Description.$invalid && form.Description.$touched || listingVm.submitted">
        <span ng-show="form.Description.$error.required">Description is required.</span>
```

.

Notice though, that ng-model still uses the controller reference:

```
ng-model="listingVm.form.Description"
```